# ¿Como evitar registros duplicados en Base de Datos?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

estoy haciendo un register en PHP, y quiero hacer que si un usuario ya esta registrado, no pueda volver a hacerlo.
En el controller tengo el siguiente codigo: `

```
                try {
                     $daoaccesori = new DAOAccesori();
                        $rdo = $daoaccesori->comprobar_usuario($_POST);


                }catch (Exception $e){
                        echo json_encode("error");
                        exit;
                    }
                    if(!$rdo){
                        echo json_encode("error");
                        exit;

                    if(mysql_num_rows($rdo)>0){
                      echo '<script language="javascript">alert("Este correo electronico ya existe");</script>'; 
                       $callback = 'index.php?page=controller_home&op=producte';
                       die('<script>window.location.href="'.$callback .'";</script>');
                      // exit;

                   }else try{
                        $daoaccesori = new DAOAccesori();
                        $rdo = $daoaccesori->nuevo_usuario($_POST);
                    }
                    catch (Exception $e){
                        echo json_encode("error");
                        exit;
                    }
                    if(!$rdo){
                        echo json_encode("error");
                        exit;
                    }else{
                                 echo '<script language="javascript">alert("Se ha registrado correctamente");</script>'; 
                                 $callback = 'index.php?page=controller_home&op=producte';
                                 die('<script>window.location.href="'.$callback .'";</script>');

                    }
                }`
```

Y el problema es que ahora no registra ni sale como que ya lo estas. 
El resultado que muestra $rdo es el siguiente: `mysqli_result Object
(
    [current_field] => 0
    [field_count] => 3
    [lengths] => 
    [num_rows] => 2
    [type] => 0
)`
Pero luego, no hace lo que quiero... Alguna sugerencia? Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente he conseguido solucionar el problema, este era que en mi sentencia SQL, me devolvia un 1 o un 0, finalmente, la consulta SQL al cumpleto se ha quedado asi:

```
function login_usuario($correo, $contrasenya){


        $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE correo='$correo' and contrasenya='$contrasenya'";


        $conexion = connect::con();
        $res = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql)->fetch_object();
        connect::close($conexion);
        return $res;
        }
```

Y el controller del login se queda tal que asi:

```
if ($_POST){

          $correo=$_POST['email'];
          $contrasenya=$_POST['contrasenya'];

                try {
                     $daoaccesori = new DAOAccesori();
                    $rdo = $daoaccesori->login_usuario($correo,$contrasenya);


                }catch (Exception $e){
                        echo json_encode("error1");
                        exit;
                    }

                 if($rdo){
                     $_SESSION['user']=$rdo;
                  /*   print_r("que te _SESSION");
                  print_r ($_SESSION['user']=$rdo);
                 // die();*/
                       echo '<script language="javascript">alert("Bienvenido!");</script>'; 
                       $callback = 'index.php?page=controller_home&op=producte';
                       die('<script>window.location.href="'.$callback .'";</script>');



                }
                else {

                        echo '<script language="javascript">alert("Email o Contraseña incorrectos");</script>'; 
                        $callback = 'index.php?page=controller_login&op=login';
                        die('<script>window.location.href="'.$callback .'";</script>');

                 }

      }

                     include("module/login/view/login.php");
        break;
```

Ahora, si que funciona $_SESSION['user']=$rdo, por lo que puedo mostrar distintos menus, dependiendo del usuario que esté registrado, entre otras cosas.

Answer (score 0):

Has recorrido el num_rows para saber que resultado te devuelve. Has probado realizar Si esta o no registrado, que devuelva una respuesta o otra,¿pregunto?

Comment: num_rows es 2. He intentado que se está registrado que te lo diga,y si no que te registre, pero nada